# How to use Font-face and background image with asset-pipeline plugin?

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-4, asset-pipeline, font-face

I'm using CodeSleeve's [asset-pipeline](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline) to manage my style sheets on my Laravel project (PHP framework). The `application.css` file is well downloaded, but **what is the method to allow images and font-face use?**

My application.css file :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mrsMonster';
    src: url('/fonts/mrsMonster/mrsmonster-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/mrsMonster/mrsmonster-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('/fonts/mrsMonster/mrsmonster-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('/fonts/mrsMonster/mrsmonster-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('/fonts/mrsMonster/mrsmonster-webfont.svg#mrs._monsterregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

#h-navbar {
    font-family: mrsMonster;
    background: url('/images/banniere.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to put the **fonts folder into the stylesheet** directory, and then write:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: Airplanes;
    src: url('fonts/airplanes/airplanes_in_the_night_sky-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/airplanes/airplanes_in_the_night_sky-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/airplanes/airplanes_in_the_night_sky-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/airplanes/airplanes_in_the_night_sky-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/airplanes/airplanes_in_the_night_sky-webfont.svg#airplanes_in_the_night_skyRg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The **images** folder can be at the same level than the **stylesheet** one's, and then you should write:

```
background: url('myImage.png');
```